# how to replace SQLAlchemy mapper deprecated "order_by" option?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a `Single Table Inheritance` sqlalchemy orm model that looks like this:

```py
class Human(Base):
    
    __tablename__ = "human"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    index = Column(Integer)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("human.id"), nullable=True)
    type = Column(String)
    parent = relationship(
        "Human",
        cascade="save-update, merge",
        backref=backref("children", cascade="all"),
        lazy=False,
        remote_side="Human.id",
    )

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type, "polymorphic_identity": "human"}

class Parent(Human):

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "parent"}

class Child(Human):

    hobby = Column(String)
    pet = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "child"}
```

This relationship looks like a nested tree, where I can query the oldest person (i.e: great grandparent, using `query.get(1)`) and then in his `children` attribute all his `children` will be present, and each child will also have their `children` present.
This relationship works just fine in every aspect.

I want the `children` that are queried when I query a `Parent` (due to lazy=False) to be ordered by the `index` column not the `id` column (which is the default).

I was achieving this by adding the following `"order_by": "index"` to the `Human` class' `__mapper_args__` as follows:

```py
__mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type, "polymorphic_identity": "human", "order_by": "index"}
```

I recently found out that in SQLAlchemy the `order_by` argument in the `mapper()` class is deprecated since SQLAlchemy version `1.1` ([reference](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html?highlight=mapper#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.params.order_by)). And that they say to use `Query.order_by()` to order the set instead, which is not working for me for some reason.

I have tried the following:

- adding `order_by` to the query, `session.query(Human).order_by(Human.index).get(1)`
- adding `order_by="Human.index"` to the `relationship()` in the `Human` class.

these two methods are not working.

How can I achieve the same effect as the `order_by` in `mapper()` now that it is being deprecated?

Comment: Also being discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5870).

Comment: @GordThompson that was me posting it there as well :)

Answer (score 4):

I got an answer after asking the question on [sqlalchemy's github](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5870).
I am posing the response in case anyone else searches for this issue and finds it here instead of sqlalchemy's github.

[The answer:](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5870#issuecomment-766420800)

> the ordering of a collection loaded by a relationship is controlled by the order_by parameter of relationship() and/or backref. In this case you want "children" to be ordered so you put that where you define "children":
>
> ```py
> parent = relationship(
>        "Human",
>        cascade="save-update, merge",
>        backref=backref("children", cascade="all", order_by="Human.index"),
>        lazy=False,
>        remote_side="Human.id",
>    )
> ```
>
> that is, this has nothing to do with mapper.order_by, although that attribute was having the effect you were seeking. if you had tried relationship->order_by on the "parent' side, that was the wrong side, it goes where the actual thing to be ordered is defined, in this case the backref.